# Is there a way to create a context menu for a gmap marker in primefaces?

Tags: google-maps, jsf-2, primefaces

Is there a way to create a context menu for a gmap marker in primefaces?

I know there is a gmapInfoWindow object, but that requires an onclick event and doesn't have the look and feel of a context menu.

I would prefer to display a context menu that appears during the onmouseover event for a gmap marker.

Please let me know if this is possible or not? Any sample code would be greatly appreciated also.

Thanks

Joe

Comment: Wow...I guess I hit a brick wall with this one as no one has answered it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code of [gmap.js](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/trunk/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/gmap/gmap.js)

I just removed the click handlers and added a listener for mouseover:

Here is the javascript code:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    var _self = gmap;
    for(var i=0; i < gmap.cfg.markers.length; i++) {
        var marker = gmap.cfg.markers[i];
        // remove all marker listener
        google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(marker);
        // add mouse over listener
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function(event) {
            _self.fireOverlaySelectEvent(event, this);
        });

       // Since we cleared all listeners adding back drag listener
       //marker drag
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(event) {
            _self.fireMarkerDragEvent(event, this);
        });
    }
});
```

Where gmap is the widgetVar attribute of `<p:gmap>`

```
<p:gmap widgetVar="gmap" />
```

Comment: Hi Ravi, Thanks a lot for your answer.  I am trying to implement it and I am getting this error:  Error Parsing /pages/map.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 64] The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.


The error is related to this line of code:

    for(var i=0; i < gmapWidget.cfg.markers.length; i++) {

Comment: OK, I got the script to run by using CData sections.  But I cannot get the code to work.  The click event still works, and the onmouseover event does not.

Comment: Did you name your gmap widget with "gmap". Also, enable Developement tools in your browser and see if you get any errors.

Comment: My problem is I don't know how to display the context menu as a dialog without a header and so that it appears relative to the currently sele cted marker instead of just anywhere on the window.

Comment: We can take this offline if you want as I am interested in maybe discussing some work / help for pay.  Email is carl.roberts.zapata@gmail.com

Comment: Sorry Carl, I am not good at everything. Can you please post another question stating that you need a dialog for the marker instead of this menu. I will try what I can do after I get off from work. If that won't suffice, I can mail you.

Comment: Thanks Ravi.  BTW, I tried changing the (window).load() event to (document).ready event as the onmouseover effect was only working during initial load of the page but then after partial refresh of the page it stops working.  My map is in a content panel that gets refreshed.  I am going to open another ticket for that one as I am trying to figure out how to call a javascript function on partial refresh of the map.

Comment: OK, I renamed the function as updateMarkers(), called $(document).ready(function(){updateMarkers();});  and then also called oncomplete="updateMarkers();" for all the menu links that do a partial refresh of the gmap so that each time gmap is refreshed it relinks the onmouseover event for the menu.  Now I just need to figure out how to hide it when the user mouses out of the menu.

Comment: For that try to add one more listener like this google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {if(this.infowindow)this.infowindow.close();});

Comment: Thanks,  I used _self.cfg.infoWindow.close();